# Is it possible to set an Empty List as a variable in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to create an empty list as a variable and like to use it in my script.But I am not able to create an empty list as a Variable? I have no idea whether we can do this in airflow or not?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. You can try to set it on `Admin > Connections`.
If you want to call it, here's an example

```
from airflow.models import Variable
foo = Variable.get("Var1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can add it via the UI or use the `airflow variables` cli:

```sh
airflow variables -s a "[]"
```

[image: Airflow Variables]